# how to save Decimal output to a variable

Tags: command-line, scripts, linux-headers

I am writing a shell script in a bash shell. I want to save the Decimal output from the command

```
ps -C firefox -o %mem,%cpu
```

to a variable.

How can I do this? The above command returns the memory utilization and CPU utilization of the Firefox process.
I want that output to be saved in a variable.

Reminder:   **The output will always be in a decimal format, not an integer**.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tail -n 1` to ignore the `%MEM %CPU` line, then, since the string you want ("`30.5 15.6`" on my system) contains a blank, quote the result:

```
a="$(ps -C firefox -o %mem,%cpu | tail -n 1)"
```

and then we see:

```
echo $a
30.5 15.6
```

Comment: `ps` (at least my one) has an option `--no-header`.

Comment: ... or use `-o %mem=,%cpu=` (rename the columns to empty names)